# IE8 only : Facebook Like Box Not Displaying

Tags: internet-explorer-8, facebook-likebox

So i've got a problem like many others : Facebook Like Box is not diplaying in IE8 (IE7 OK).
I found many posts about that, tried all solutions but did not succed...
IE8 message : **FB.FBXML Null or not an object**

NB : there's a function which handle resizing of FB Like Box.

Here's my HTML5 code :

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="fr"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
...
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
    <article>
    <div class="row" id="content">
            <div class="twelvecol last">
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
                <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/divstudio" data-width="1140" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </article>
...

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        var contentwidth = $('#content').width();
        $('.fb-like-box').attr('data-width', contentwidth - '40');
        FB.FBXML.parse(document.getElementsByClassName('.fb-like-box'));
});
</script> 

 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>      
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas ?

website : http://www.divstudio.fr/emergenza/jazz/actu.html

thx a lot

Answer (score 4):

You should add these lines to the  tag.

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

If there are already any attributes in the  tag, leave them as it is. So that the starting html tag becomes like this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" lang="<?php print $language->language ?>" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir ?>">
```

Clear the cache if caching is enabled. It should work in IE-8

Comment: Should this be added in the header?

Comment: Yes, in the starting html tag

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and adding the appropriate xmlns attributes did not help.  As it turns out, what was causing my problem is related to another problem: [Facebook like box not showing up when user is not logged into Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268100/facebook-like-box-plugin-doesnt-show-up-for-logged-out-users-only-for-logged-i).  Igy and wasim kazi had the answers that led me to the solution.  Here's how to solve the problem:

1. Log onto the Facebook account that manages the page you want reflected in the like box.
2. On the left nav bar, click on "Pages".
3. Click on the page title to bring up the admin panel for that page.
4. Click on Edit Page -> Edit Settings
5. You'll see a box labeled "Country Restrictions".  If there are ANY countries listed in this box, your like box will be blank if the user isn't logged onto Facebook AND **it will be blank in Internet Explorer (7, 8, 9)**.  This makes sense: the only way Facebook would be able to enforce geographic restrictions with any certainty would be by making sure the user is logged in.  Why this affects IE (whether the user is logged in or not) is a mystery, but that was the cause of the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the facebook module for drupal 6.

I solved my problem by changing the markup type from **XFBML** to **HTML5**

I then added the HTML5 script in the `<head>` section:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I hope this fixes your problem as well.