# Facebook Like Box is blank

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

I am using the iframe method to get the Facebook Like Box on my website.
The website is: http://motorcyclealley.co.nz (the Like Box should be showing down the bottom to the right of the YouTube video)

However, it is always blank.

Browsing to the iframe url in my browser: http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/MotorcycleAlley&width=320&height=315&show_faces=false&colorscheme=light&stream=true&border_color&header=false&appId=397375460320824

Also produces a blank screen. The url was generated with the [official generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/). I am unable to figure out what is wrong because STRANGELY it works in the browser I originally did it on (Firefox 18.0.2 on Linux).

I have tried it on Chrome, Internet Explorer and Firefox/Windows and made sure that all adblocking extensions are disabled. I still get the blank screen.

Can anyone tell me whats going on?

EDIT: I should also mention that I have tried the HTML5 and FBML methods with the same result, they both worked on that ONE browser but not on any others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just found out why. The Like Box doesnt show unless you're logged into Facebook in that browser (because it is set to have an age restriction). Apparently the following fixes it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310091/335227

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I followed [FB's instruction](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) to add a FB like box in my web page:

```html
  <div class="fb-like" 
       data-href="https://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
       data-width=""
       data-layout="standard" 
       data-action="like" 
       data-size="small"  
       data-share="true">
  </div>
```

But the block doesn't show like and share buttons, only white blank.

After some investigation I found it to be a bug of standard layout, if I set data-layout attribute to box_count, button_count or button, it works well.

[My research](https://blog.darkthread.net/blog/fix-fb-like-box-blank-issue-en/)