# Empty iFrame for Facebook content embedded on page

Tags: facebook, iframe

I have the following code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F%3Fref%3Dlogo%23%21%2Fpages%2FCadenamovitel%2F144895632232758%3Fref%3Dsgm&amp;width=230&amp;connections=10&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=587" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:230px; height:587px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And when I try to navigate to the url that loads the iframe it works well. But when I put this iframe inside my webpage, the content is not loaded, I just get an empty iframe. The wierd thing is that if I change the page referenced by the like box, it shows correctly in my webpage. For example:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F%3Fref%3Dlogo%23%21%2Fpages%2FMovistar%2F115204311836948%3Fref%3Dsgm&amp;width=230&amp;connections=10&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=587" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:230px; height:587px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

So I think it's a permissions related issue, but I couldn't find the option to allow it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Like Box is blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804339/facebook-like-box-is-blank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! It was a demographic and an age rectriction in my page, and it seems that dissables the social plugins **unless a facebook session is opened and match that criteria.** Removing both restrictions allows the plugin to show correctly!