# Facebook like box not showing

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I have included a Facebook Like box on a website i am creating and it only shows up when they are logged into facebook. When they have looged out the like box disappears not allowing anyone new to the site being able to see it. I have included all the code facebook tell you to put in but no joy.

Could anyone help me please.

The code i have used:

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

HTML code

```
<div id="fb_like">
<fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Emma-Nolan-Mobile-Beauty-    and-Holistic-Therapy/230397297018772" width="300" height="185" show_faces="true"     stream="false" header="false" border_color="#FFFFFF"></fb:like-box>
</div>
```

The site is not using HTML5 so im using the XFBML. Is this something to do with the Facebook settings itself? This is a business page only.

Ive put the script in the head tag and at the bottom of the page to allow for loading, also placed it straight under the body tag as metioned by Facebook.

Comment: Is it not showing at all? Or does it only display the likebutton.

Comment: "I have included all the code face tell you to put in but no joy."? Not sure what that sentence means, but can you please show us the code you are using?

Comment: @John - maybe he means "...all the code facebook tell..."

Comment: Ive updated the first question

Cheers guys

Comment: After reading some more on the net the owner of this business also has a personal account but they are not linked. Do they have to be for this wto work?

Answer (score 1):

**Add namespace** to the html tag of your document.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Add this code **directly below the < body > tag**.  Note: make sure to **append the correct app id** to the js sdk.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YourAppIdHere";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

there was white space in your fb url for the target page.

```
<div id="fb_like">
<fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Emma-Nolan-Mobile-Beauty-and-Holistic-Therapy/230397297018772" width="300" height="185" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="false" border_color="#FFFFFF"></fb:like-box>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Shawn, I have already put the new namspace directly under the <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> namespace. Is this correct? sorry the white space was my fault not inputting in here properly. This is not there in the code. How do i get the App ID? An App was not created, all i did was go to the developers site, filled in the form with the accounts URL altered font, size etc and followed the instructions.

Comment: 1.  Name space must be for open graph "og".
2.  App Id can be your page id from what i understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been dealing with this issue. Does the cient/business owner have any country or age restrictions set for their page? When demographic restrictions are set (allowing only visitors from a specific country for example, or excluding visitors from a specific country), the Fb like box will not display for non logged-in users. This is a consequence of setting demograhic restrictions and as far as i know cannot be resolved except by opening up the page and getting rid of all restrictions. Hope this helps. See similar thread here: [Facebook Like Box plugin doesn't show up for logged out users; only for logged in users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268100/facebook-like-box-plugin-doesnt-show-up-for-logged-out-users-only-for-logged-i)

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't included [javascript sdk](http://www.shoutingblogger.com/2013/01/add-facebook-like-button-in-blogger.html) in your head tag ,resulting in improper fb like button rendering .