# Facebook likebox disappears when logged out

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-likebox

Trying to show facebook likebox in my Wordpress site, I followed the instructions given here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

It's working as long as I'm logged in to facebook myself, but when I'm logged out the like box disappears.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Check your code again. Issue not related with FB i think.

Comment: Code was copied from the Facebook link I gave above without any changes.
This also happens with Wordpress plugins, such as Wordbooker.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268100/facebook-like-box-plugin-doesnt-show-up-for-logged-out-users-only-for-logged-i

Comment: Thanks, but I saw it.
Both the app and the page are public with no age or country restrictions and are not alcohol related.
This is why it's so puzzling to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Although my country and a few others were set, the likebox wouldn't show when logged out.
Once I removed all countries from the list everything worked properly.

Comment: What countries and what list are you talking about? I'm having the same problem, it seems the URL in data-href doesn't actually exist anymore