# Facebook Like Box not showing if you are not logged in Facebook on same browser

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, html

Facebook Like Box code (a bit modified than orgiginal to make it responsible in Bootstrap):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=477903835654837";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.fb-like-box,.fb-like-box span,.fb-like-box span iframe[style] {
    width: 100% !important;
}
</style>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/wineslv"
    data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false"
    data-stream="true" data-show-border="false" data-width="350"
    data-height="800" width="100%"></div>
```

Working perfect only if I am logged in on the same browser. If I'm not logged in to Facebook, the content is not showing up. Any suggestions how to get content even if user is not legged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. The problem is not with the code, it's because of the Facebook restrictions.
Here is an answer: [Facebook Like Box plugin doesn't show up for logged out users; only for logged in users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268100/facebook-like-box-plugin-doesnt-show-up-for-logged-out-users-only-for-logged-i)