# Facebook Page plugin not previewing

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I go [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) on the facebook developer site to get the code for a facebook page plugin.

The preview works for any page, such as "facebook.com/Nike" etc... but when I try my page, "facebook.com/BargainHideout", it does not preview at all, and thus, does not show on my shopify site either.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with your page url, and it's blank for me as well. But after I generate code with one of the page I own, it showed up perfectly. So, make sure you are logged into Facebook & you own the page and you will see the preview as well as in your site. See the screenshots below:

**Your page:**
[image]

**My page:**
[image]

**UPDATE**

Make sure you see this answer as well: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310091/3515968)

Cheers!